# Java If statement not functionining as intended

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make a simple enough if statement that creates a range of intergers, in this case => 0 and <= 250, but it doesn't seem to work at intended. No matter what value height is, it doesn't ever pull it up and run the second block.

```
public static void display(int height, int weight)
{
    if(height >= 0 && height <= 250 )
    {
        System.out.println( format() );
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter a height (in cm) above 0 and below 250");
    }
}
```

Here is the `format()` code:

```
    public static String format()
{
    String name = "Harry Potter";
    int height = 256;
    int weight = 84;
    return String.format( "Name:\t %s %n" + "Height:\t %scm%n" + "Weight:\t %skg%n", name, height, weight);
}
```

Comment: Write `>=` instead of `=>`.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped it on here

Comment: Show us the code for `format()`

Comment: @MarounMaroun Shouldn't => give a syntax error?

Comment: When writing the `>=` and `<=` symbols, speak them ("greater than or equal to") and write them in the order you'd speak them (in English at least).

Comment: @Ingo It will.. I thought he was getting a compilation error.

Comment: Print out your `height` value before the if statement.

Comment: What are you doing with `weight`?  Are you using it in the method? If not, why have it as a parameter?

Comment: It seems okay and will work just fine. What values are you providing and how. Also , Why dont you debug it and see what the values are you getting to make sure that the correct values are passed.

Comment: I've tested your code, and it works (tested with height = -4, 10, 1000).

Comment: y u dint used "weight" parameter ??

Comment: How do you call `display` method? Show us the client (caller) code.

Comment: Its better you provide us the code where you are calling the `display(int,int)` method so we can deduce what is wrong.

Comment: Something looks off with the logic. The weight and height are coming from the `format()` method, but OP is trying to compare in `display()` method

Comment: @peeskillet I haven't made the if statemnt for `weight` yet, I'm following the instructions left for me atm

@SaifAsif i'll give it a try

@neutrino Yeah, I don't understand why its not working as intended :/

Answer (score 0):

its working here.Take a look

```
public class Grocery
{//start class

 public static void main (String []args)
{//start main
 display(4,5);

}//end main


public static void display(int height, int weight)
{
if(height >= 0 && height <= 250 )
{
    System.out.println( format() );
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Please enter a height (in cm) above 0 and below 250");
}
}
   public static String format()
{
String name = "Harry Potter";
int height = 256;
int weight = 84;
return String.format( "Name:\t %s %n" + "Height:\t %scm%n" + "Weight:\t %skg%n", name, height, weight);
}
   }//end class
```

**Output**

Name:    Harry Potter

Height:  256cm

Weight:  84kg

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want something more like this.

```
public static String format(int weight, int height, String name) {
     return String.format( "Name:\t %s %n" + "Height:\t %scm%n" 
                         + "Weight:\t %skg%n", name, height, weight);
}

public static void display(int height, int weight, String name) {

    if(height >= 0 && height <= 250 ) {
        System.out.println( format(height, weight, name) );
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a height (in cm) above 0 and below 250");
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = scanner.nextLine();
    int weight = scanner.nextInt();
    int height = scanner.nextInt();

    display(wieght, height, name);
}
```